# What part of web site to be WSP / WAP?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-applications, vs-web-site-project

I'm new to ASP.NET, and would like an understanding of when/where to use WSP vs WAP.

I will make a rather simple business website, with 6-7 pages, where one page will open a registration/login form where the user can see various personal data and reports, pulled from a database.

Would this suggest the use of a combination of WSP and WAP, where for example the login window is part of the WSP, and a successful login opens a WAP in a frame or in a new browser window/tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mmhh you are confused with the notion of  web application  and web site.

You cannot make one page in one way and another the other way, because WAP and WSP are type of project. So it is at the beginning of your project in visual studio to decide which one to use.

Basically, WSP is leaving the compilation of your code to IIS, and so you are working only with files. Using WAP, your project behaves like in a normal application, Visual studio will then compile your code to create different dll. You will then have only to move to your production environment the page aspx and the dlls, whereas with WSP, you would also include aspx.cs.

this [link](http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/171/wap-or-wsp-which-to-use-and-why.aspx) will tell you everything you might want to know

hope it helped,

Comment: Yes I will use WAP for the pages where the user is logged in and interact with the database. As I don't want this code exposed. I thought WAP had too limited design features to make a nice standard web page, but maybe that is not true..